# Diary app with quick date selection and browsing and bookmarks

Tags: android, git, google-drive, diary

On the Google Play store there are several diary applications, such as [My Diary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adpog.diary).

However, I am looking for a diary application with the following features:

- quicker date picking, bookmarking, and bookmark referencing:

I would like a widget that looks like a clock pop up via a button on top of the notes for a given day while allowing them to be seen in the background. This widget, allows the user to select the day, on the outer circle, the month, on the inner circle, with days and months numbered around the circle, and the year, via a text box with up and down arrows to the side. When the numbers on this widget are selected, the day with the notes on the diary appears in the background (observer design pattern), allowing the user to see immediately if it is the day with the notes they were looking for our not (they may not remember when exactly they did a given thing, and may need to browse this way), and move about quickly.

The days can also be browsed without this widget, by swiping left and right.

- The notes can be locked, meaning, that when you view it it cannot be edited. This can be done via a special button, that ensures data integrity of the notes in the diary (so that they are not accidentally deleted or lost. You may want to have revisioning of the notes in a git backend integrated into the app to ensure note integrity even further.
- Each note can be bookmarked via a special bookmark button. When a note is bookmarked, you can enter a note description for that date and the date appears in the application menu under a bookmark section below which appear all the dates with their corresponding bookmark names.
- You can highlight note entries on any given date, using highlight colors, and search note entries.
- The notes (or, better, the notes repository, for all the dates, is stored on Google Drive).

I think such an app would be nice, efficient, and handy.

Anyone come up with such code?

Is anyone willing to write it or have this code implemented?

I am willing to pay a one time fee for this app, and I think several users would find it useful.

Thank you for your contribution.

Thanks.